# Voleur au moyen-âge

Tags: histoire, ancien-français

En cherchant [les étymologies de *voler*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voler#%C3%89tymologie), pour voir si l'un des sens venait de l'autre ou s'ils avaient des origines différentes, j'ai appris que *voler* dans le sens *dérober* vient de *voler* comme un oiseau, mais surtout qu'il n'a supplanté *rober* qu'au XVII<sup>e</sup> siècle. [*Voleur*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voleur#%C3%89tymologie) quant à lui date du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle (1549).

Ce qui signifie que jusqu'à la fin du moyen-âge, probablement personne ne disait "*Au voleur !*". Le wiktionnaire indique qu'on utilisait "*rober*" et "*dérober*" avant que *voler* ne devienne l'usage, mais ne dit rien pour "*voleur*".

Quel mot utilisait-on pour "*voleur*" avant que "*voler*" ne soit usité dans ce sens ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La lecture de textes en ancien et moyen français atteste de l'emploi du mot ***robeor*** qui signifie « voleur », lequel l'a peu à peu remplacé à partir du 16<sup>e</sup> siècle.

> *Li **robeor**, plein de malice,
>
>   s’asemblerent quant seul le virent,
>
>   et par maintes foiz le batirent,
>
>   quant les biens venoient enbler.*<sup>1</sup>
>   (*[Le roman de la Rose](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Roman_de_la_Rose_(Guillaume_de_Lorris_et_Jean_de_Meung))*, Jean de Meun, 1269-1278)

Texte complet accessible par la [Base de Français Médieval](http://txm.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/bfm/?command=documentation&path=/CORPTEF).

> *La resons pour quoi sainte Eglise ne doit pas garantir les **robeurs** des chemins si est tele, que tuit crestien, de droit commun, doivent sauf aler et sauf venir par les chemins.*
>    (Philippe de Beaumanoir, [*Coutumes de Beauvaisis*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coutumes_de_Beauvaisis), *ca*. 1263)

Texte complet accessible par la [Base de Français Médieval](http://txm.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/bfm/?command=documentation&path=/CORPTEF).

> *Ja nel metra fors a nul fuer,
>
>   Tant crient larrons et **robeors** ;
>
>   Mes de neant li vient peors*<sup>2</sup>
>   ([*Cligès*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clig%C3%A8s) de Chrétien de Troyes, 1176)

Texte complet accessible par la [Base de Français Médieval](http://txm.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/bfm/?command=documentation&path=/CORPTEF).

Le « Dictionnaire de Godefroy » (*[Dictionnaire de l'ancienne langue française et de tous ses dialectes du IX<sup>e</sup> au XV<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k50640w/f2.item.zoom)*, Frédéric Godefroy, 1880-1895) donne comme traduction de ***robeor*** :   **voleur, pillard**.

Les [très nombreux exemples](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/robeor)  donnés par Godefroy donne une idée de la fréquence du mot qu'on trouve sous différentes formes : *robeour, robeur, robbour, roubauour, reubeor, robaor, robeur*, selon les textes (l'orthographe du français n'a commencé à se fixer qu'à partir du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle).

Le ***robeor*** c'est celui qui prend la *robe*. La [*robe*](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/lexique-godefroy/robe) c'est le butin, la dépouille (→ le vêtement de celui qui est mort et qui reste sur champ de bataille). Puis le sens a évolué vers « vol, larcin » puis vers « vêtements » (sens générique) et enfin vers le vêtement féminin de ce nom.
Le mot vient du [vieux haut allemand](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieux_haut_allemand) [*roub*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/rauben) (8<sup>e</sup> siècle) qui signifiait « butin ». En allemand moderne *rauben* est encore employé pour dire « voler » dans le sens de « dérober ».

Il existait aussi le nom dérivé *[desrobeor (desrobeur)](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/desrobeor)*.  Le verbe « dérober » est resté en français moderne mais *desrobeur* n'est (quasiment) plus utilisé (considéré comme très vieilli).

Au gré des textes on trouve des mots avec des sens voisins (je ne prétends pas être exhaustif) :

- ***Pillard*** (fem. pilleresse, pillard) c'est celui/celle qui *pille* (prend). ([Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/lexique-godefroy/pillard), [Lacurne](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-lacurne/pillard))
- ***Larcineur*** (*larchonneur*), celui qui commet un larcin. ([Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/larcineur)). Le français moderne a gardé le nom « larcin » qui est le délit et aussi la chose prise. « Larcin » vient du latin *latrocinium* (vol à main armé, brigandage).
- ***Larron*** (*laron, ladron, ladrun, larun, lairron*) celui qui commet un larcin, qui dérobe furtivement. ([Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/larron)). Terme issu du latin *latro* et qui désignait un soldat (un mercenaire grec), puis un brigand. Existait aussi le verbe *larroner*.

---

Sources :
[Base de Français Médiéval](http://txm.ish-lyon.cnrs.fr/bfm/?command=documentation&path=/CORPTEF).
[Dictionnaire de Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/introduction/dictionnaire-godefroy).
[Lexique de l'ancien français de Godefroy](http://micmap.org/dicfro/introduction/lexique-godefroy).
[Dictionnaire de Lacurne](http://micmap.org/dicfro/introduction/dictionnaire-lacurne).
*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey, 1999, éditions Le Robert.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Les voleurs dans leur méchanceté se rassemblèrent quand ils le virent seul et le frappèrent plusieurs fois tant les biens les avaient éblouis. (Traduction personnelle non officielle)

<sup>2</sup> Jamais elle ne lui permettra de sortir, elle qui craint tant les larrons et les voleurs, mais elle a tort d'avoir peur (Traduction de @aCOSwt).</sub>

Comment: Oui! Absolument et +1. On a side note pour en rire : j'observerai que le lexique étendu de l'époque relativement à ces gens-là s'est considérablement restreint... dans d'autres langues aussi. On pourra à loisir s'amuser à considérer que l'allemand traduit le *larrons et robeors* du Cligès par *Dieb und Räuber* et que... si on tape ce truc dans google translate pour obtenir la traduction française... on obtient ! : *"voleur et voleur"*... No comment!

Comment: @aCOSwt Tu ne m'aurais pas dit que le phénomène se constatait dans d'autres langues aussi j'aurais accusé Richelieu qui a quand même mis un sacré carcan sur la langue française dont on a du mal à se débarrasser encore aujourd'hui.

Answer (score 0):

Selon le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/larron), le mot « larron » remonte à assez loin dans le temps et a signifié « voleur », sous la forme première de « ladron », depuis la fin du X<sup>e</sup> siècle, puis sous la forme « larrun » à partir de 1130 ;

> Étymol. et Hist. 1. Fin Xe s. ladron, ladrun « voleur » (*Passion*, éd. D'Arco Silvio Avalle, 163 et 223); 1130 larrun (*Lois G. le Conquérant*, éd. J. E. Matzke, § 4); d'où 1656 s'entendre ... comme larrons en foire (MOLIÈRE, *Dépit amoureux*, III, 8);

Comment: Intérressant ! J'avais remarqué notamment qu'en espagnol, "*voler*" se disait "*robar*", conservant l'origine latine. Et en espagnol, voleur se dit "*ladrón*", qui vient bien du latin *latro* :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Avec tout ce bagage comment n'avoir pas pensé à « larron » ?

Comment: @LPH On ne peut pas penser à tout!

Comment: Intéressant, incluant les sources ([1](http://txm.bfm-corpus.org/pdf/passion.pdf), [2](https://archive.org/details/romania31romagoog/page/n313), [3](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k55632g/f68.image)). La totale ce serait d'avoir un contexte où on a « au larron ! » comme « au voleur ». Est-ce qu'on avait vraiment ça ou on formulait ça autrement avant le 16e ? La question demeure... p.s. si tu fais une modif. stp. mettre les titres d’œuvres en italiques et ajouter le lien au TLF.